# Google Maps Places: Why do I need an API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the official documentation it is said that I need to have an API key and my accesses will be limited according to whether I am a free user or a premium user: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

I need to access the API as `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places`

However, when I look at examples, they do not use an API key. They simply call the API as:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places
```

I am confused why I need to obtain an API key while the examples available do not use any API key.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues), not coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required API key is a recent change that was announced on June 22, 2016.

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Indeed before June 22, 2016 it was possible do not use an API key, from now on it's required.